# Wercker: Build failing on 'set up environment'. Why?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, jekyll, wercker

I have a Jekyll blog which I'm trying to push to an AWS S3 bucket. I have followed [this tutorial](http://manuelgruber.com/2014/jekyll-bitbucket-to-aws-s3/).

The build keeps failing. Wercker gives me the following error message:

> Build failed on master
>
> setup environment
>
> GET https://registry.hub.docker.com/v1/repositories/wercker/ruby/images returned 404

It the displays my wercker.yml file:

```
box: wercker/ruby
no-response-timeout: 10
build:
 steps:
     - bundle-install
     - script:
         name: Run Jekyll doctor
         code: bundle exec jekyll doctor
     - script:
         name: Build Jekyll site
         code: bundle exec jekyll build --trace
deploy:
 steps:
     - s3sync:
         key_id: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
         key_secret: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
         bucket_url: $AWS_BUCKET_URL
         source_dir: _site/
         opts: --acl-public --add-header=Cache-Control:max-age=3600
```

I'm out of my depth here. Google is only returning other Wercker pages with the same error message. What is causing the error? What steps do I need to take to fix this?

Here's a [link](https://app.wercker.com/#buildstep/56aa44947bcbc993600026bd) to the error page itself.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Solved!

It appears that the tutorial is outdated.

I needed to update wercker.yml to work with Wercker v2.

To do this, I changed:
`box: wercker/ruby`
to
`box: ruby`.

Comment: It's a shame all of the Wercker tutorials are outdated. I fell victim to the same problem when deploying my Jekyll project in Wercker. Thanks for posting the answer.

Comment: Lots of the Wercker documentation has recently been updated, as they have revamped their website.